# Security mechanisms for commands sent to spacecraft

Tags: security

Is there any publicly known security mechanism for remotely controlling spacecraft such as the rovers on Mars? It seems like adding any type of encryption may lessen the reliability, but if there is no security isn't there a risk of malign actors attempting to send harmful commands to spacecraft?